# What should be the code for lambda function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

**This is python code for dataframe**

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
names = {'First_name': ['Hanah', 'Ria', 'Jay', 'Bholu', 'Sachin'],
'Status':['Hanah', 'Ria', 'Jay', 'Bholu', 'Sachin'],
"charge":[10,11,12,13,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(names)
```

**This is the lambda function for generating output**

```
df['Status'] = df['First_name'].apply(lambda x: [df["charge"]] if x == 'Ria' else 'Not Found')
print(df)
```

**The output generated is this:**

```
df['Status'] = df['First_name'].apply(lambda x: [df["charge"]] if x == 'Ria' else 'Not Found')
print(df)
```

**The output is**

```
  First_name                  Status  charge
0      Hanah               Not Found      10
1        Ria  [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]      11
2        Jay               Not Found      12
3      Bholu               Not Found      13
4     Sachin               Not Found      14
```

**But I want to generate the output**

```
  First_name                  Status  charge
0      Hanah               Not Found      10
1        Ria                      11      11
2        Jay               Not Found      12
3      Bholu               Not Found      13
4     Sachin               Not Found      14
```

**So as in second row it is Ria so I have to fetch the result of charge(column) in second row and put it in status(column)**

Comment: `df['Status'] = df['charge'].where(df['Status'].eq('Ria'), 'Not Found')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want use `apply` and lambda func, apply lambda func to all dataframe with `axis=1`

```
df['Status'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['charge'] if x['First_name'] == 'Ria' else 'Not Found', axis=1)
```

`df`

```
    First_name  Status  charge
0   Hanah       Not Found   10
1   Ria         11          11
2   Jay         Not Found   12
3   Bholu       Not Found   13
4   Sachin      Not Found   14
```

---

but we can use `mask` instead `apply`

```
cond1 = df['First_name'].ne('Ria')
df.assign(Status=df['charge'].mask(cond1, 'Not Found'))
```

result:

```
    First_name  Status  charge
0   Hanah       Not Found   10
1   Ria         11          11
2   Jay         Not Found   12
3   Bholu       Not Found   13
4   Sachin      Not Found   14
```

Answer (score 0):

lambda can be used in the place of def function
First_name                  Status  charge
0      Hanah               Not Found      10
1        Ria                      11      11
2        Jay               Not Found      12
3      Bholu               Not Found      13
4     Sachin               Not Found      14
this table can eaisly be conn using def

Comment: I am not getting can you please share code